# How to remove text from the beginning of every line, and paste it to the end of each line in terminal

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have a long list of numbers and values that look something like this:

```
100 value1 value2
```

There are roughly 150 lines in this list, and I want to move every number to the end of the values, so that it looks like this:

```
value1 value2 100
```

I've tried using this command to do the job:

```
awk -F: '{print $2 $3 $1}' ~path/to/file.txt
```

but it just prints everything in the file

```
100 value1 value2
101 value3 value4
102 value5 value6
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason your awk command didn't do anything: you're telling awk that colon is the field separator. There are no colons, so the entire line is the first field.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you were close. :)

Try with:
`awk '{print $2,$3,$1}' filename >  output_file`

And check it with:
`cat output_file`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ num = $1;$1=""; sub(/^ /,""); print $0,num; }' ~path/to/file.txt
```

That allows for any number of columns. Explanation:

- Save the first column into variable "num" and then set it to nothing (ie "")
- Remove the extra space between the first two columns (using sub)
- Print

  - $0 - the entire row
  - "num" the original first column

You could also use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/' ~path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: Good though with the backspace, but you're printing it at the start of the line where it can't do anything. I think you need to do `sub(/^ /,""); print $0, num` or `print substr($0, 2), num`

Comment: @glennjackman - it worked using Cygwin, further testing has shown this is not the case with other terminals - thanks